# Read more than 3000 txt files by using loop

Tags: matlab

I have more than 3000 Data txt files. I create the name for these file according to special rate by this code

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
%%
h=[1];
k_plus =[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_T =[1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_D = [1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
sets = {k_plus, K_minus_T, K_minus_D,h};
[x,y,z r] = ndgrid(sets{:});
cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:) r(:)];
nFiles = size(cartProd,1);
filename{nFiles,1}=[];
for i=1:nFiles
    filename{i} = ['MTN100_' ...        
        'k+'  num2str(cartProd(i,1)) '_' ...
        'k-T_' num2str(cartProd(i,2)) '_' ...
        'k-D' num2str(cartProd(i,3)) '_' ...
        'h'  num2str(cartProd(i,4)) '_' ...
        'GTP0.txt'];
    end
```

Now I want to read each file in the loop and do some processing. I tried to use textscan and textread but It is not work.

```
h=[1];
k_plus =[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_T =[1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_D = [1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
sets = {k_plus, K_minus_T, K_minus_D,h};
[x,y,z r] = ndgrid(sets{:});
cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:) r(:)];
nFiles = size(cartProd,1);
filename{nFiles,1}=[];
for i=1:nFiles
    filename{i} = ['MTN100_' ...        
        'k+'  num2str(cartProd(i,1)) '_' ...
        'k-T_' num2str(cartProd(i,2)) '_' ...
        'k-D' num2str(cartProd(i,3)) '_' ...
        'h'  num2str(cartProd(i,4)) '_' ...
        'GTP0.txt'];
    file1=fopen(filename{i},'r')
    C=textscan(filename{i},'%u');

  t1      = C(1,:);
  d1      = C(3,:);
  plot(t1, d1, 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 3);
  fclose(filename{i});
end
```

I am mainly using C++ and not really familiar with how to do the similar things in MATLAB.Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Not sure if you made the error when copy pasting it here but in your second code block you use inside your for-loop `C=textsacn` I am pretty sure that should be `textscan`

Comment: Define "not work" - it gives an error, the data you read is not what you expect, what? To use `textscan` properly you have to know what the format of the text file contains - are there header lines, how many columns, how are they delimited, etc.

Comment: Dear  nkjt, each file contain 7 columns with data type (real values). It does not contain header lines

Comment: If you are just trying to read numbers arranged in regular blocks you'd be better off starting with `dlmread`.  As ever, the comprehensive Matlab documentation is a good guide to its use.

Comment: Dear  High Performance Mark, I treid to use (dlmread) but it dosed not work

Comment: As @nkjt said, you really should provide more detail that "it does not work" as it's often that information that helps people to solve the problem. Not working might mean that you're getting error messages or just that you're not getting the result you expected. The more detail you provide, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: file1{i}=dlmread(filename{i});
    t1= file1 (:,1);
    d1= file1 (:,2);

Comment: If `file1{1}` is the array returned by `dlmread` then attempting to get only the first column of the array by using `file1 (:,1)` won't work. You need something like `file1{1}(:,1)`.  I can't check exactly, I don't have Matlab on this machine.  But rest assured, `dlmread` DOES work and when you use it properly you will find it much easier than messing around with `textscan` if you are just trying to read a block of numbers from a file to a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is that you're experiencing, but I spotted a couple of errors in your code. `fopen` returns a file ID, it's this file ID that you should then pass into `textscan` and `fclose`, not the file name. The second argument to `textscan` is the format specifier of a single row of the data that you're scanning. You mentioned in the comments that there are 7 real values, I've set the `formatspec` to `'%f%f%f%f%f%f%f'` which will treat the values as doubles. If your values are delimited with anything other than whitespace you'll need to add delimiter information to the textscan call.

```
h=[1];
k_plus =[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_T =[1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_D = [1e-6 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
sets = {k_plus, K_minus_T, K_minus_D,h};
[x,y,z r] = ndgrid(sets{:});
cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:) r(:)];
nFiles = size(cartProd,1);
filename{nFiles,1}=[];
for i=1:nFiles
    filename{i} = ['MTN100_' ...        
        'k+'  num2str(cartProd(i,1)) '_' ...
        'k-T_' num2str(cartProd(i,2)) '_' ...
        'k-D' num2str(cartProd(i,3)) '_' ...
        'h'  num2str(cartProd(i,4)) '_' ...
        'GTP0.txt'];
    file1=fopen(filename{i},'r')
    C=textscan(file1,'%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
    fclose(file1);

    t1      = C(1,:);
    d1      = C(3,:);
    plot(t1, d1, 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 3);
end
```